# Using Initializer Syntax on a C# Property

Tags: c#, arrays, initializer

In C#, this is valid syntax:

```
int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

I'm trying to use similar syntax with a property on my object:

```
MyClass myinst = new MyClass();              // See Class Definition below
myinst.MinMax = {-3.141, 3.141};             // Invalid Expression
myinst.MinMax = new double[]{-3.141, 3.141}; // Works, but more verbose
```

Can I do anything like my desired syntax?

---

**Class Definition**

```
class MyClass
{
    public double[] MinMax
    {
        set
        {
            if (value.Length != 2) throw new ArgumentException();
            _yMin = value[0];
            _yMax = value[1];
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `double` syntax is redundant, as the type of the array can be inferred by the property's type, so the best you can do is this:

```
myinst.MinMax = new[] {-3.141, 3.141};
```

Comment: Its a shame my preferred syntax won't work, since I don't think the `new[]` says anything that cannot be fully inferred by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

You can drop `double` but other than that, it's all required.

```
myinst.MinMax = new [] {-3.141, 3.141};
```

If you're really intent on shortening it, you can create a helper function like this, but it's an extra function call (not a big deal, just something to know).

```
private static void Main()
{
    int[] a = A(1, 2, 3);

    double[] b = A(1.2, 3.4, 1);
}

private static T[] A<T>(params T[] array)
{
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The shortest valid form is:

```
myinst.MinMax = new[] { -3.141, 3.141 };
```

The shorter form you have mentioned is called an array initializer, but you cannot use it in a property setter. The reason being that array initializers are not actually expressions and calling a property setter requires an expression on the right hand side. Array initializers are only valid in the context of a field declaration, local variable declaration, or array creation expression (i.e. `new[] { -3.141, 3.141 }`).